# How can I check if a user has a certain role in JSP?

Tags: jsp, roles

I need to make decisions in a JSP based on the user's  roles. Is there a tag or EL expression that lets me do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't one built into JSP or JSTL, but the [request taglib](http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/doc/request-doc/) from the Jakarta project provides an [`isUserInRole`](http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/doc/request-doc/#isUserInRole) tag. [Install](http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/doc/request-doc/index.html#config) the taglib, and use the tag like this:

```
<req:isUserInRole role="admin">
 The remote user is in role "admin".
</req:isUserInRole>
<req:isUserInRole role="admin" value="false">
 The remote user is not in role "admin".
</req:isUserInRole>
```